# Radio active decay formula is not growth formula, $p = p_0 * e^{kt}$, what is the formula for radio active decay, and why?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, exponential-function

Trying to solve this question:
A radioactive material is known to decay at a yearly rate proportional to the amount at each moment. There were 2000 grams of the material 10 years ago. There are 1990 grams right now. What is the half-life of the material?

I've set it up as $p = p_0 * e^{kt} \implies 1990 = 2000 * e^{k(10)}$, then solve for k, but that doesn't seem to work.

The formula they give below seem to imply I should use negative k, which I suppose I can reconcile since it's a decay instead of growth.

However I cannot understand why they would:

- replace e with 2..? (Where did the e go..?)
- Assume H = time, why they would divide it by time..?

[image]

Comment: $2 = e^{\mathrm{log}(2)}$. In pre-calculus, they write these things in base $2$; in calculus, they write everything in base $e$; and soon you will have the superpower to quickly switch between these viewpoints.

Comment: thanks @TorstenSchoeneberg, I get that. But where did the $e^{\mathrm{log}(2)}$ even come from, to allow us to convert it into 2? More importantly, what is the decay formula...? (And why... if you have the time to help me)

Comment: From the intention to express the number $2$ in base $e$.

Comment: Why would we want to express the number 2 in base e ? What is wrong with the exponential formula $p = p_0 * e^{kt}$ applied to radioactive decay? Or does it not translate?...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. It's just that for radioactivity, some people like to express it with base $2$ instead of base $e$, because one likes to talk of "half-life". If you are able to convert from base $2$ to base $e$ and back, there should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks @TorstenSchoeneberg, I can't understand where the opportunity to convert it is (I see why we should convert- because people like it..). More importantly.. If I comprehend what you're saying correctly, you're saying $p = p_0 * e^{kt}$ is indeed correct one to use? If so I'm stuck here, I've got the value of k but don't understnad how to proceed further. can you help? https://ibb.co/thCcxJw

Comment: If $k<0$ it is exponential  radioactive decay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a "formula" for radioactive decay which is $p(t) = p_0e^{-kt}$ where $p_0 > 0$, $k> 0$ and $t > 0$. So in this case, we know the following: $p_0 = 2000$ and $p(10) = 1990 = 2000e^{-10k}$. This leads to $k = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1990}{2000}\right)}{-10} \approx 0.000501254182354$.

But more importantly, we need to transform this into $p = p_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{t}{k}}$, then whenever $t = k$ is a half-life. So now the real formula presents itself:

$$
1990 = 2000\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{10}{k}}
$$

Then we solve:

$$
\frac{10}{k} = \frac{\log\left(\frac{1990}{2000}\right)}{\log\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} \leadsto k = 10\frac{\log(2)}{\log\left(\frac{2000}{1990}\right)} \approx 1382
$$

**A word about $r^\frac{t}{k}$**

You could just have easily written $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{t}{k}} = 2^{-\frac{t}{k}}$. It's probably even more canonical to write $2^{\pm kt} = 2^{\pm \frac{1}{\lambda}t}$. And that gets to the point of writing it one way or the other: for $2^{kt}$, $k$ is a "frequency" (that's hard to relate within a real exponential) and $\lambda = \frac{1}{k}$ is a "wavelength"--a distance--in this case a period of time: the half life...or third life...or three quarters life or even the exotic $\frac{1}{e}$ life--it's whatever base you decide you want:

$$
p_n = p_0\cdot \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{\lambda}\cdot\{t = n\}} \leadsto \lambda = n\frac{\log(b)}{\log\left(\frac{p_0}{p_n}\right)}\text{, where }b > 1, n > 0, p_0 > p_n
$$

Note that in this formula, the assumption is that it's a decay, i.e. that this can be written as $p_0b^{-kt}$ where $b > 1$ and $k > 0$. A negative exponential *defines* a decay! But we can rewrite knowing what a negative exponential means: $b^{-kt} = \frac{1}{b^{kt}} = \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^{kt}$. Then, by rewording to $k = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ we can ask what happens when $t = \lambda$, i.e. the exponent equals $1$.

Comment: Hi thanks for the amazing answer, for some reason math stack over flow doesn't allow me to type in math of the following statement so here's an [upload](https://ibb.co/nQ41qxh) of my question. // trying math type again... Ignore if it doesn't work and I can't fix in the 5 mins I have... Can you help me understand why $\frac{10}{k} = \frac{\log(\frac{1990}{2000})}{\log(\frac{1}{2}$ ? If $k = \frac{\ln(\frac{1990}{2000})}{-10}$ shouldn't $\frac{t}{k} = \frac{10}{\frac{\ln(\frac{1990}{2000})}{-10}}$?

Comment: @nvs0000 I'm guessing you are confusing $e^{-kt} \leadsto k = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1990}{2000}\right)}{-10}$ with $p(t) = p_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{t}{k}} \leadsto \frac{10}{k} = \frac{\log\left(\frac{2000}{1990}\right)}{\log(2)}$. These are two _different_ $k$-values and aren't related to one another...well they are actually: if we know $k$ for $p(t) = p_0e^{-kt}$ then we can compute $t$ for $\frac{p_0}{2} = p_0e^{-kT_{half}} \leadsto T_{half} = \frac{1}{k}\ln(2)$ (which you can verify for the $k$ I found).

Comment: Note: $\log\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = -\log\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$ meaning that $\frac{\log(a)}{\log(b)} = \frac{\log\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\log\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)}$.